# Table breaks after remove row using css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm creating this table using php:

```
<?php foreach ($jogos as $jogo) { ?>
                                <tr timeCasa="<?= $jogo->timeCasa; ?>" idCampeonato="<?= $jogo->id_campeonato; ?>" timeadversario="<?= $jogo->timeAdversario; ?>" data="<?= $jogo->data; ?>">
                                    <td class="data"><?= $jogo->data; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $jogo->timeCasa; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $jogo->timeAdversario; ?></td>
                                    <td><button class="btnAposta btn" tipo="<?= $jogo->timeCasa; ?>" data-selected="false"  id="<?= $jogo->id; ?>"> <?= $jogo->valorCasa; ?></button></td>
                                    <td><button class="btnAposta btn" tipo="Empate" data-selected="false" id="<?= $jogo->id; ?>"> <?= $jogo->valorEmpate; ?></button></td>
                                    <td><button class="btnAposta btn" tipo="<?= $jogo->timeAdversario; ?>" data-selected="false" id="<?= $jogo->id; ?>"> <?= $jogo->valorFora; ?></button></td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php } ?>
```

that results: 
[image]

but when i try to remove a row using javascript/css breaks the css:
(i have buttons to show some rows and remove some rows, depends of idCampeonato.
exemple: i want to show championships with id 1, so i get the ID and hidden all and show all of ID.

```
function mostrarCampeonatos(event) {
console.log(event.id);
var tbody = document.getElementById("tabela").childNodes[1].rows;
var tabelaT = $('tabela');
console.log(tbody);

for(var i=1;i<tbody.length;i++) {
    //console.log(tbody[i].getAttribute("idcampeonato"));
    console.log(tbody[i]);
    if(event.id=="todos") {
        //tbody[i].setAttribute("class", "showrow");
        tbody[i].className = "showrow";
    } else {
        if (event.id != tbody[i].getAttribute("idcampeonato")) {
            //tbody[i].setAttribute("class", "hiddenrow");
            tbody[i].className = "hiddenrow";
        } else {
            //tbody[i].setAttribute("class", "showrow");
            tbody[i].className = "showrow";
        }
    }


}
```

}

my css:

[image]

table after apply css to remove row:
[image]
is the best way to remove a row?

Comment: are you using Datatables?

Comment: Your css, for `.showrow` try `display: table-cell;`

Comment: no, i'm not using datatables.

Comment: add the class `hiddenrow` while hiding and remove it while showing, dont add the `showrow` class

Comment: @Reddy how could i implement it?

Comment: @pess0a, try `tbody[i].className = ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `<tr>` element as `inline` via the `.showrow` class.

User @Xorifelse already gave you the solution. Just remove this css code:

`.showrow {
      display: inline;
    }`

or set it to:

`.showrow {
      display: table-row;
    }`